# If something happens in 25 % of all cases in every generation, what will the frequency converge to in the long run?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I just saw this map http://consang.net/images/c/c4/Globalcolourlarge.jpg (available on Archive.org if it would ever disappear) and become curious about how inbred people actually are.

3 scenarios:

1. In quite a few countries around 25 % of all marriages are between cousins. If that number is constant over the generations, how inbred is the average person living in such a country?
2. In the worst countries around 50 % of all marriages are between cousins. Same question as in (1).
3. And the same the question for the countries with only 1 % cousin marriages.

Where do these three scenarios converge? Naïvely I figured it should be at 50 %, 100 % and 2 % but I can't really motivate that guess.

Comment: What does "inbred" mean in this context?

Comment: What do you mean by "inbred"? Is it enough to have blood from a common ancestor at any level of the ancestry tree? Do you allow for marriages between people of different generations?

Comment: @MarkBennet Marriage between cousins or (genetically) closer relatives.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo That is basically the question. Since 25 % of all marriages are between cousins the average person is 25 % inbred in the current generation, 37.5 % (I reckon?) if you include the previous generation, 43,75 % including two generations back and so on? That is my intution but I have problems putting up an equation for it. Yes, if they are genetically as close as, or closer than, cousins.